# Seeking SF short story with "slow" in title

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a SF short story with the word slow in the title.  It might have been in one of Gardner Dozois's anthologies ages ago.  I believe it was about someone being chased on a spaceship and the motivation for the chase may have to do with the politics of the chaser/chasee.

Title may have been something like:

The slow (   )   Of  (      )

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please add more detail if possible: Here is an article on how to ask a good and helpful story id question: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: possible? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153226/sci-fi-short-story-about-a-fight-and-a-decades-long-chase-through-space

Comment: possible? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133353/not-with-a-whimper-but-with-a-roar-of-triumph - (certainly has a multi-syllabic title as OP seems to feel the story in question has)

Comment: Story probably published between 1980-2000give or take few years.  And I'm 57.

Comment: Thanks NKC but neither of the two links you mentioned were the story.

Comment: Story was in an anthology probably Gardener Dozier (?sp)

Comment: Was the person being chased inside the spaceship, or was the spaceship itself being chased?