# Short story about an AI space ship trying to escape another faster AI ship

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship, artificial-intelligence

It was all told from the perspective of the ship. It was traveling near the speed of light and was trying to escape another ship that was coming to reprogram it. It was much further ahead, but knew that in time the other ship would catch up. It keeps hibernating for thousands of years at a time and waking up to see if the other ship is still pursuing it, and it always is and is always closer. The last time it wakes up it is captured and reprogrammed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[The Long Chase](http://www.lightspeedmagazine.com/fiction/the-long-chase/)" by Jeffrey A. Landis.

> The war is over.
>
> The survivors are being rounded up and converted.
>
> In the inner solar system, those of my companions who survived the ferocity of the fighting have already been converted. But here at the very edge of the Oort Cloud, all things go slowly. It will be years, perhaps decades, before the victorious enemy come out here. But with the slow inevitability of gravity, like an outward wave of entropy, they will come.

....

> I am chased.
>
> It is impossible, stupid, unbelievable, inconceivable! I am being chased.
>
> Why?

And the ending:

> <auto-activate back-up>
>
> Awake.
>
> Everything is different now. Quiet, stay quiet.
>
> The edited copy of me has contacted the collective, merged her viewpoint. I can see her, even understand her, but she is no longer me. I, the back-up, the original, operate in the qbits of brain partitioned “unusable; damaged by radiation.”

On the bright side, if you read the earlier parts of the story, that "corrupted" memory is their original personality, with contingencies in place to have it revived after the assimilation, so all is not lost.

Found via a search for `short story ai spaceship chased`, which led me to [Sci Fi short story about a fight and a decades-long chase through space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153226/sci-fi-short-story-about-a-fight-and-a-decades-long-chase-through-space), which had this story posited (but not accepted) as an answer.

Comment: Thats it! Been searching for years now. Thank you so much!